# jquery - submit files with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not sure how to do that -

I have form with text fields and number of files input (images)
how do i submit the files with ajax?
how the jquery script should look like?

```
<form id="attrac-form-<?PHP echo $mainIndex['id'] ?>" action="#"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="attrac-form">

      <input type="file" name="file[]">

      <input type="file" name="file[]">

      <input type="file" name="file[]">

      <input class="attrac-submit" value="SEND" type="submit" >

    </form>
```

This is my current js for the text field

```
$(document).on("click", ".attrac-submit", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).closest('form').serializeArray();
        formData.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'});        

        submitAtractionForm (formData);

});


function submitAtractionForm(formData)
{

    $.ajax ({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'ajax/attractions.php',
      data: formData,
      dataType    : 'json',
      async: false,
      code        : true
    }).done(function(data) 
    {
        ...
    });

}
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) SO question

Comment: @JeroenHeier - how should it works when i have array of files?